# Issue Downloading Complete Webpage Programmatically

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I've been having an issue with downloading webpages automatically with WebClient. Here are the steps my code runs through:

1. Retrieve HTML as string
2. Iterate through string, retrieving valid content urls (.js, .css, .png, etc.)
3. Download the content
4. Replace urls in HTML string with the content's local file path.
5. Save new HTML string to "main.html".

Everything is downloaded just fine. When I try to open up the html file in Chrome, it's a blank loading screen (varies from 10 seconds to 30 seconds). When the page finally loads, it looks like basic text and broken content.

The errors in the Chrome's Developer Tools suggest a lot of the .js and .css files aren't there, even though I've verified most of them are in the specified directory. [image]

I have tried multiple sites, each with the same result.

Here is the code to retrieve the html data:

```
    public string ScanPage(string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning url [" + url + "].");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", userAgent);
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/html");

        string page = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            page = client.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine("Webpage has been scanned.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error scanning page: " + e.Message);
        }

        client.Dispose();
        return page;
    }
```

Begin downloading data. This method is called first.

```
    public void DownloadPageContent(string url, string contentDirectory, params string[] customExtensions)
    {
        //PathSafeURL(url) takes the url and removes unsafe characters
        contentDirectory += PathSafeURL(url);
        if (Directory.Exists(contentDirectory))
            Directory.Delete(contentDirectory, true);

        if (!Directory.Exists(contentDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(contentDirectory);

        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        string host = uri.Host;

        //PageResponse is used to check for valid URLs. Irrelevant to the issue.
        PageResponse urlResponse = CheckHttpPageResponse(url);
        if (urlResponse.IsSuccessful())
        {
            //Get the html page as a string.
            string data = ScanPage(url);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                //Download files with ".js" extension.
                DownloadByExtension(ref data, ".js", contentDirectory + "/", "scripts/", host);

                //Same as above, but with .css files.
                DownloadByExtension(ref data, ".css", contentDirectory + "/", "css/", host);

                //Iterate through custom extensions (.png, .jpg, .webm, etc.)
                for (int i = 0; i < customExtensions.Length; i++)
                    DownloadByExtension(ref data, customExtensions[i], contentDirectory + "/", "resources/", host);

                string documentDirectory = contentDirectory + "/main.html";
                File.Create(documentDirectory).Dispose();
                File.AppendAllText(documentDirectory, data);

                Console.WriteLine("Page download has completed.");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving page data. Data was empty.");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Page could not be loaded. " + urlResponse.ToString());
    }

    public void DownloadByExtension(ref string data, string extension, string contentDirectory, string subDirectory, string host)
    {
        List<HtmlContent> content = new List<HtmlContent>();
        IterateContentLinks(data, extension, ref content, host);
        CreateContent(contentDirectory, subDirectory, content);

        for (int i = 0; i < content.Count; i++)
            data = data.Replace(content[i].OriginalText + content[i].Extension, content[i].LocalLink);

        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded " + content.Count + " " + extension + " files.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    private void IterateContentLinks(string data, string extension, ref List<HtmlContent> content, string host)
    {
        int totalCount = data.TotalCharacters(extension + "\"");
        for (int i = 1; i < totalCount + 1; i++)
        {
            int extensionIndex = data.IndexOfNth(extension + "\"", i);
            int backTrackIndex = extensionIndex - 1;

            //Backtrack index from the extension index until you reach the first quotation mark.
            while (data[backTrackIndex] != '"')
            {
                backTrackIndex -= 1;
            }

            string text = data.Substring(backTrackIndex + 1, (extensionIndex - backTrackIndex) - 1);
            string link = text;

            if (link.StartsWith("//"))
                link = link.Insert(0, "http:");
            if (link.StartsWith("/"))
                link = link.Insert(0, "http://" + host);
            if (!link.Contains("/")) //Assume it's in a "test.jpg" format.
                link = link.Insert(0, "http://" + host + "/");

            content.Add(new HtmlContent(text, link, extension));
        }

        //Remove repeating links
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < content.Count; j++)
            {
                if (content[i].OriginalText == content[j].OriginalText)
                    content.Remove(content[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    private void CreateContent(string contentDirectory, string subDirectory, List<HtmlContent> content)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(contentDirectory + subDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(contentDirectory + subDirectory);

        Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        for (int i = 0; i < content.Count; i++)
        {
            content[i].RandomName = Extensions.RandomSymbols(random, 20, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
            content[i].LocalLink = contentDirectory + subDirectory + content[i].RandomName + content[i].Extension;

            bool isSuccessful = false;
            DownloadFile(content[i].DownloadLink + content[i].Extension, content[i].LocalLink, ref isSuccessful);

            if (isSuccessful == false)
                content.Remove(content[i]);
        }
    }
    private void DownloadFile(string url, string filePath, ref bool isSuccessful)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", userAgent);
            //client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "image/jpg");

            try
            {
                client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
                isSuccessful = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                isSuccessful = false;
                Console.WriteLine("File [" + url + "] could not be downloaded.");
            }
        }
    }
```

HTMLContent class:

```
public class HtmlContent
{
    public string OriginalText { get; private set; }
    public string DownloadLink { get; private set; }
    public string Extension { get; private set; }

    public string LocalLink { get; set; }
    public string RandomName { get; set; }

    public HtmlContent(string OriginalText, string DownloadLink, string Extension)
    {
        this.OriginalText = OriginalText;
        this.DownloadLink = DownloadLink;
        this.Extension = Extension;
    }
}
```

As a file downloader, this works good. For HTML downloading, it's good too. But as a complete offline webpage downloader, it does not.

EDIT:

Not sure if it matter, but I forgot to show what the userAgent variable looks like:

```
private const string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36";
```

Comment: The process you've described will only work if client-side content is completely static, but that's not true for many web sites.  Often there are scripts which, when executed, load even more scripts, images, and/or stylesheets.  User interaction (like scrolling, or clicking on buttons) can also trigger scripts which load additional content.

Comment: @RogerN, would it be possible to iterate through the downloaded scripts and download the additional content? Or is that getting too complex.

If you know of any quicker alternatives, I'd love to know. I saw the "WebBrowser" route earlier, but popping up the save dialog is putting me off.

Comment: No, that won't work as a universal solution because content URLs are sometimes formed programmatically.  You'd have to execute the scripts (requiring full DOM support), and even then there might be runtime-specific variables (e.g. timestamps or session IDs) in the URLs.  A full-featured web browser can do a better job, as it's already loaded the page and executed the scripts, but it still won't work 100% because it cannot predict future user interactions which might cause additional content to load.